# Elasticsearch, sort aggs according to sibling fields but from different index

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch v7.5

Hello and good day!

We have 2 indices named **socialmedia** and **influencers**

Sample contents:

**socialmedia:**

```
{
    '_id' : 1001,
    'title' : "Title 1",
    'smp_id' : 1,
},
{
    '_id' : 1002,
    'title' : "Title 2",
    'smp_id' : 2,
},
{
    '_id' : 1003,
    'title' : "Title 3",
    'smp_id' : 3,
}
//omitted other documents
```

**influencers**

```
{
    '_id' : 1,
    'name' : "John",
    'smp_id' : 1,
    'smp_score' : 5
},
{
    '_id' : 2,
    'name' : "Peter",
    'smp_id' : 2,
    'smp_score' : 10
},
{
    '_id' : 3,
    'name' : "Mark",
    'smp_id' : 3,
    'smp_score' : 15
}
//omitted other documents
```

Now I have this simple query that determines which **influencer** has the most document in the **socialmedia** index

```
GET socialmedia/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "INFLUENCERS": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "smp_id.keyword"
        //smp_id is a **text** based field, that's why we have `.keyword` here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "INFLUENCERS" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : //omitted,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : //omitted,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 87258
        },
        {
          "key" : "2",
          "doc_count" : 36518
        },
        {
          "key" : "3",
          "doc_count" : 34838
        },
      ]
  }
}
```

**OBJECTIVE:**

My query is able to sort the **influencers** according to *doc_count* of their posts in the **socialmedia** index, now, is there a way for us to sort the **INFLUENCERS** aggregation or make a way to sort out the **influencers** according to their **SMP_SCORE**?

With that idea, **smp_id** 3 which is Mark, should be the first one to appear since he has an **smp_score** of 15

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why are smp_id and smp_score fields indexed as string?

Comment: hello @kumarD, only "smp_id" is indexed as string coz the actual `smp_id` looks like this **d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e**, I just made it single number here to explain easily the situtation

Comment: the **smp_score** is indexed as float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a JOIN operation. Note that Elasticsearch doesn't support JOIN operations unless they are modelled in a way as mentioned in [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html).

Instead, a very simplistic approach is to denormalize your data and add the `smp_score` to your `socialmedia` index as below:

### Mapping:

```
PUT socialmedia
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword":{
            "type":"keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "smp_id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "smp_score": {
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your ES query would then have two [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) as shown below:

### Request Query:

```
POST socialmedia/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "influencers_score_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "smp_score",
        "order": { "_key": "desc" }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "influencers_id_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "smp_id.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically we are first aggregating on the `smp_score` and then introducing a sub-aggregation to display the `smp_id`.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_influencers_score" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 15.0,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "influencers" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "3",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 10.0,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "influencers" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "2",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 5.0,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "influencers" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "1",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Do spend sometime in reading the above link, however that would require you to model your index in a different way depending on the options mentioned in it. From what I understand, the solution I've provided would suffice.

Comment: well I guess you're correct sir, Elasticsearch is a denormalized database where all fields should have been placed in a single index. There seems no other way than to reindex the mappings :/ thank you very much!

Comment: hey sir @Opster, do you have any idea for my new inquiry? this is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871585/elasticsearch-terms-aggs-according-to-sibling-nested-fields

Comment: Sure, I will look into it and let you know. I will respond probably by EOD today.