# Elasticsearch, terms aggs according to sibling nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch v7.5

Hello and good day!

We have 2 indices named **socialmedia** and **influencers**

Sample contents:

**socialmedia**:

```
{
    '_id' : 1001,
    'title' : "Title 1",
    'smp_id' : 1,
    "latest" : [
        {
          "soc_mm_score" : "5",
        }
    ]
},
{
    '_id' : 1002,
    'title' : "Title 2",
    'smp_id' : 2,
    "latest" : [
        {
          "soc_mm_score" : "10",
        }
    ]
},
{
    '_id' : 1003,
    'title' : "Title 3",
    'smp_id' : 3,
    "latest" : [
        {
          "soc_mm_score" : "35",
        }
    ]
},
{
    '_id' : 1004,
    'title' : "Title 4",
    'smp_id' : 2,
    "latest" : [
        {
          "soc_mm_score" : "30",
        }
    ]
}
```

//omitted some other fields

**influencers**:

```
{
    '_id' : 1,
    'name' : "John",
    'smp_id' : 1
},
{
    '_id' : 2,
    'name' : "Peter",
    'smp_id' : 2
},
{
    '_id' : 3,
    'name' : "Mark",
    'smp_id' : 3
}
```

Now I have this simple query that determines which *documents* in the **socialmedia** index has the most **latest.soc_mm_score** value, and also displaying their corresponding **influencers** determined by the **smp_id**

```
GET socialmedia/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": "latest", 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "LATEST": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "latest"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "MM_SCORE": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "latest.soc_mm_score",
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            },
            "size": 3
          },
          "aggs": {
            "REVERSE": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggs": {
                "SMP_ID": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "_source": ["smp_id"], 
                    "size": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "LATEST" : {
      "doc_count" : //omitted,
      "MM_SCORE" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : //omitted,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : //omitted,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : 35,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "REVERSE" : {
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "SMP_ID" : {
                "hits" : {
                  "total" : {
                    "value" : 1,
                    "relation" : "eq"
                  },
                  "max_score" : 1.0,
                  "hits" : [
                    {
                      "_index" : "socialmedia",
                      "_type" : "index",
                      "_id" : "1003",
                      "_score" : 1.0,
                      "_source" : {
                        "smp_id" : "3"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : 30,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "REVERSE" : {
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "SMP_ID" : {
                "hits" : {
                  "total" : {
                    "value" : 1,
                    "relation" : "eq"
                  },
                  "max_score" : 1.0,
                  "hits" : [
                    {
                      "_index" : "socialmedia",
                      "_type" : "index",
                      "_id" : "1004",
                      "_score" : 1.0,
                      "_source" : {
                        "smp_id" : "2"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : 10,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "REVERSE" : {
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "SMP_ID" : {
                "hits" : {
                  "total" : {
                    "value" : 1,
                    "relation" : "eq"
                  },
                  "max_score" : 1.0,
                  "hits" : [
                    {
                      "_index" : "socialmedia",
                      "_type" : "index",
                      "_id" : "1002",
                      "_score" : 1.0,
                      "_source" : {
                        "smp_id" : "2"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

with the query above, I was able to successfully display **which documents** have the highest **latest.soc_mm_score** values

The sample output above only displays **DOCUMENTS**, telling that the **influencers (a.k.a smp_id)** related to them are the TOP INFLUENCERS according to **latest.soc_mm_score**

Ideally just by using this aggs query,

```
"terms" : {
    "field" : "smp_id"
}
```

portrays the concept of which influencers are the **top** according to the **doc_count**

Now, displaying the terms query according to **latest.soc_mm_score** displays **TOP DOCUMENTS**

```
"terms" : {
    "field" : "latest.soc_mm_score"
}
```

**REAL OBJECTIVE**:

I want to display the **TOP INFLUENCERS** according to the **latest.soc_mm_count** in the **socialmedia** index. If Elasticsearch can count all the documents where according to unique smp_id, is there a way for ES to sum all **latest.soc_mm_score** values and use it as **terms**?

My objective above should output these:

- smp_id 2 as the Top Influencer because he has 2 posts (with soc_mm_score of 30 and 10), adding them gets him 40 soc_mm_score
- smp_id 3 as the 2nd Top Influencer, he has 1 post with 35 soc_mm_score
- smp_id 1 as the 3rd Top Influencer, he has 1 post with 5 soc_mm_score

Is there a proper query to meet this objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY! FOUND AN ANSWER!!!

```
"aggs": {
    "INFS": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "smp_id.keyword",
        "order": {
          "LATEST > SUM_SVALUE": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "LATEST": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "latest"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "SUM_SVALUE": {
              "sum" : {
                "field": "latest.soc_mm_score"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**Displays the following sample:**

[image: FINAL]